# How do I pass arguments on a query from Firestore in jetpack compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I have a query in my project to retrieve a list of Games and display it in a lazyColumn. It is working all right when I query the entire collection, but I want to put a whereIn clause that takes 2 arguments that I have to pass in the fragment and I don't know how to pass it with Jetpack Compose.

Below is the query that is already in place and working:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("queryGame")
    fun provideGetAllGames(): Query =
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection(GAMES)
}
```

```
@Singleton
class PlayersRepository @Inject constructor(  
    private val queryGame: Query,
) {
 fun getPlayerFromFirestore(): DataOrException<Task<DocumentSnapshot>, Exception> {
        val dataOrException = DataOrException<Task<DocumentSnapshot>, Exception>()
        try {
            dataOrException.data = getUser.get()
        } catch (e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
            dataOrException.e = e
        }
        return dataOrException
    }
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class GamesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PlayersRepository
): ViewModel() {
 val data: MutableState<DataOrException<List<Game>, Exception>> = mutableStateOf(
        DataOrException(
            listOf(),
            Exception("")
        )
    )

    init{
       getAllGames()
    }

   fun getAllGames() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            data.value = repository.getAllGames()
        }
    }
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class GameFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: GamesViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
     return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                      val games = viewModel.data.value.data
LazyColumn{
           items(games!!){ game ->
            GameResults(game)
    }
 }
```

I need to add  .whereIn(PLAYERS, listOf(user1 + "*" + user2, user2 + "*" + user1)) in the appModule but I don't know how will I pass the user1 and user2 on the fragment. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to add .whereIn(PLAYERS, listOf(user1 + "" + user2, user2 + "" + user1)) in the appModule

You cannot pass dynamic data into the AppModule file. So to use a Query object to getting data from Firestore, you need to add that `.whereIn()` call in your repository class. Seeing that you have already injected the "queryGame" object (which is actually a CollectionReference object) into your repository class, you can use the following line of code:

```
dataOrException.data = queryGame.whereIn(PLAYERS, listOf(user1 + "" + user2, user2 + "" + user1)).get()
```

Don't forget to pass both, "user1" and "user2" objects in the method where you are using this query.

Comment: But how will I pass the arguments when I call the function on viewModel? The function is been called in the Init{} block in viewModel and it updates the data MutableState

Comment: If you are getting the  "user1" and "user2" objects in your activity class, then you should pass them as arguments into the ViewModel class, and then pass them in terms into the repository class.

Comment: Hi Henrique! Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes, I think I got everything set for now. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear that, Henrique ;)